# Python avoid curly braces when subprocess call is done to an expect script

Tags: python, tcl, expect

I have the following expect script named autossh.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set user [lrange $argv 0 0] 
set password [lrange $argv 1 1] 
set ipaddr [lrange $argv 2 2]
set command [lrange $argv 3 3]
set timeout 10
# now connect to remote UNIX box (ipaddr) with given script to execute
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$ipaddr 'bash -s' < $command
expect "*?assword:*"
# Send password aka $password
send -- "$password\r"
interact
# send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
#send -- "\r"
```

I am calling this expect script from a python file  which is like below

```
import subprocess
user = "abc"
operation = "l"
password = "xyz"
brokerip = "10.XX.XX.XXX"
command = ' topics.sh '+operation+' '+user
subprocess.call(['autossh.exp', user, password, brokerip, command])
```

I want to pass the topics.sh (which is locally) found to ssh.

When i run the python file i get the below error.

```
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc@10.xx.xx.xxx 'bash -s' < { topics.sh l abc}
tmhaskar@xx.xx.xx.xxx's password: 
bash: {: No such file or directory
```

Can some one tell me is there any work around to avoid the curly braces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, why did you start your `command` with a space?

Comment: And how do you use this `autossh.exp` script from the command line?

Comment: have you tried changing this `'bash -s' < $command` to `'bash -s < $command'`?

Comment: @anzel: Are you sure that will work? Isn't `lrange $argv 3 3` going to parse the string into a list, which you then need to re-stringify somehow (`lindex` maybe?).

Comment: One last thing: Since you appear to know Python pretty well, and Tcl not so much, why not use `pexpect` from within Python instead of subprocessing out to a separate `expect` script?

Comment: @abarnert, good call. didn't pay attention to the $argv part. let me check

Comment: I think [this](http://codepad.org/doEsDiOj) demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Anyway, I've added the tcl tag, because I think a Tcl expert will be a lot more help here than me…

Comment: @abarnert : I started command with space because initially when there was no space it gave me error bash: {command: No such file or directory , thats why i thought of separating it. Also I dont want to use pexpect since I am not sure if it will be there on server where this code will reside.

Comment: Well, `lrange $somelist $abc $abc` (i.e., same index used twice) is usually an indication of a mistake. It's a bit of a code smell…

Answer (score 1):

Try using `lindex` rather than `lrange`. lrange attempts to return a well formed list, so if it finds certain characters in the data it will add braces or backslashes to guarantee you get a valid list even if it's a list with a single element. lindex, on the other hand, returns a single element from a list.

```
% set argv [list abc xyz 10.xx.xx.xxx "topics.sh 1 abc"]
abc xyz 10.xx.xx.xxx {topics.sh 1 abc}
% lrange $argv 3 3
{topics.sh 1 abc}
% lindex $argv 3
topics.sh 1 abc
```

Comment: I changed from lrange to lindex, the script now gives me topics.sh not found error, whereas the topics.sh is exists. I tried to give absolute path still it does not work.                            spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no abc@10.xx.xx.xxx 'bash -s' < topics.sh l abc  is the new ssh statement.

Comment: Oh, duh, my suggestion to `lrange` the argv array and then `lindex` the result was pretty silly when you can just `lindex` the argv array directly, wasn't it…